Rust WASM memory ptr is not same as JS Arraybuffer offset
I try to pass json content from js to rust with zero copy, but is seems the memory where rust vec ptr point to is not same as js arraybuffer with offset.

My Env:

cargo 1.83.0

wasm-pack 0.13.1

wasm-bindgen 0.2.63



<lib.rs>

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn load_data(ptr: *mut u8, size: usize) -> i32 {
    utils::set_panic_hook();
    log(&format!("{:?}", ptr));

    let u8array = unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, size, size) };

    log(&format!("{:?}", u8array));

    log(&format!("{:?}", String::from_utf8(u8array).unwrap()));
    return 0;
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn malloc_u8_array(size: usize) -> *const u8 {
    utils::set_panic_hook();

    let mut vec: Vec<u8> = vec![128;size];
    vec.as_ptr()
}

<index.js>
wasm_app().then(
    (output) => {
        fetch("./data.json").then(
            resp => resp.arrayBuffer()
        ).then(
            (buf) => {
                console.log(new Uint8Array(buf));
                let ptr = wasm.malloc_u8_array(buf.byteLength);
                console.log("Ptr:", ptr)
                console.log(output.memory);
                let data_view = new Uint8Array(output.memory.buffer, ptr, buf.byteLength);
                for (let i = 0; i < buf.byteLength; i++) {
                    data_view[i] = buf[i];
                }

                wasm.load_data(ptr, buf.byteLength);
            }
        )
    }
)

This is js Uint8Array output: Uint8Array(56) [123, 10, 32, 32, 34, 97, 34, 58, 32, 49, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 98, 34, 58, 32, 50, 44, 10, 32, 32, 34, 99, 34, 58, 32, 91, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 49, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 50, 44, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 51, 10, 32, 32, 93, 10, 125, buffer: ArrayBuffer(56), byteLength: 56, byteOffset: 0, length: 56, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Uint8Array']
And this is rust u8vec output : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
Is the ptr rust return not correct offset to WASM memory?

Vec::as_ptr only takes a reference to the Vec, so the Vec ends up getting dropped at the end of malloc_u8_array. This means ptr is dangling, and so Vec::from_raw_parts leads to immediate undefined behavior.
You could avoid dropping the Vec by using Vec::into_raw_parts instead of Vec::as_ptr. The stable version of this is let ptr = vec.as_ptr(); followed by std::mem::forget(vec) before returning ptr. There is, however, a way to write the code without unsafe:
Note that wasm_bindgen allows passing objects such as ArrayBuffer or Uint8Array directly between Rust and JavaScript, not just primitive types like integers and pointers. In this case, I recommend converting the ArrayBuffer to a Uint8Array in JavaScript, passing that to Rust as an argument of type js_sys::Uint8Array, and calling Uint8Array::to_vec to get a Vec with the data. This is no less efficient than allocating the Vec in advance.

Thanks a lot,I used crate raw_parts cuz into_raw_parts is unstable and this resolved my problem!The reason why I dont use object passing is that the data size may reach several hundred megabytes in my production environment,so copy is intolerable.

@NightmareRevisited glad your problem is resolved. If you want a stable version of into_raw_parts, use as_ptr followed by std::mem::forget(vec) before returning the ptr. Regarding copying, note that passing an js_sys::Uint8Array object between JavaScript and Rust does not intrinsically copy the several hundred megabytes in the array. The copying takes place in your for loop or in Uint8Array::to_vec, though I suppose you could optimize your for loop with TypedArray.set.

I just checked the js_sys source code and the copying in Uint8Array::to_vec is optimal for performance. It allocates a Vec of the right size (like you do manually), doesn't pre-initialize it (your code does, possibly costing CPU cycles), and does a single TypedArray.set call to do the copying to the Vec's location in WebAssembly memory (you can't beat the performance, especially not with your for loop).
